# File Upload + MySql Does Not Work

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a simple script to upload images, but something does not work for me.. I tried evrything, but I cant figure out why file is not saved on the server and why the path is not saved in mysql..

PS: There is no PHP errors..

submit.php

```
<form onSubmit="return validateForm()" action="offer_save.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask">                            

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="title">Title: <span class="required">*</span></label>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" name="title" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
         </div>          
        </div>        

        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="start_day">Offer Start: <span class="required">*</span></label>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <select name="start_day" id="start_date">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="11">11</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
              <option value="13">13</option>
              <option value="14">14</option>
              <option value="15">15</option>
              <option value="16">16</option>
              <option value="17">17</option>
              <option value="18">18</option>
              <option value="19">19</option>
              <option value="20">20</option>
              <option value="21">21</option>
              <option value="22">22</option>
              <option value="23">23</option>
              <option value="24">24</option>
              <option value="25">25</option>
              <option value="26">26</option>
              <option value="27">27</option>
              <option value="28">28</option>
              <option value="29">29</option>
              <option value="30">30</option>
              <option value="31">31</option>
            </select>

            <select name="start_month" id="start_date">
              <option value="01">January</option>
              <option value="02">February</option>
              <option value="03">March</option>
              <option value="04">April</option>
              <option value="05">May</option>
              <option value="06">June</option>
              <option value="07">July</option>
              <option value="08">August</option>
              <option value="09">September</option>
              <option value="10">October</option>
              <option value="02">November</option>
              <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>

             <select name="start_year" id="start_date">
                <option value="2016" selected="selected">2016</option>
                <option value="2017">2017</option>
             </select>         
           </div>          
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="end_day">Offer Start: <span class="required">*</span></label>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <select name="end_day" id="start_date">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="11">11</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
              <option value="13">13</option>
              <option value="14">14</option>
              <option value="15">15</option>
              <option value="16">16</option>
              <option value="17">17</option>
              <option value="18">18</option>
              <option value="19">19</option>
              <option value="20">20</option>
              <option value="21">21</option>
              <option value="22">22</option>
              <option value="23">23</option>
              <option value="24">24</option>
              <option value="25">25</option>
              <option value="26">26</option>
              <option value="27">27</option>
              <option value="28">28</option>
              <option value="29">29</option>
              <option value="30">30</option>
              <option value="31">31</option>
            </select>

            <select name="end_month" id="start_date">
              <option value="01">January</option>
              <option value="02">February</option>
              <option value="03">March</option>
              <option value="04">April</option>
              <option value="05">May</option>
              <option value="06">June</option>
              <option value="07">July</option>
              <option value="08">August</option>
              <option value="09">September</option>
              <option value="10">October</option>
              <option value="02">November</option>
              <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>

             <select name="end_year" id="start_date">
                <option value="2016" selected="selected">2016</option>
                <option value="2017">2017</option>
             </select>         
           </div>          
        </div> 

     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="description">Description <span class="required">*</span></label>
             <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
               <textarea name="description" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></textarea>
             </div>          
     </div>  

  <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="category">Industry <span class="required">*</span></label>
               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
                <option value="Automotive">Automotive</option>  
                <option value="Business & Economy">Business & Economy</option>  
                <option value="Careers & Jobs">Careers & Jobs</option>  
                <option value="Computers">Computers</option>  
                <option value="Education & Training">Education & Training</option>  
                <option value="Entertainment & Media">Entertainment & Media</option>  
                <option value="Health & Beauty Care">Health & Beauty Care</option>  
                <option value="Industry">Industry</option>  
                <option value="Internet & WWW">Internet & WWW</option>  
                <option value="Law">Law</option>  
                <option value="Life">Life</option>  
                <option value="Real Estate">Real Estate</option>  
                <option value="Science">Science</option>  
                <option value="Shopping & Services">Shopping & Services</option>  
                <option value="Small Business">Small Business</option>  
                <option value="Society">Society</option>  
                <option value="Sports">Sports</option>  
                <option value="Telecommunications">Telecommunications</option>  
                <option value="Travel & Recreation">Travel & Recreation</option>  
        </select> 
         </div>          
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="price">Price (in €): <span class="required">*</span></label>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" name="price" required="price" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
         </div>          
        </div>   

        <p>
          <label for="fileToUpload">Thumb:</label>
          <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        </p>

           <input type="hidden" name="user_id" size="30" maxlenght="40" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>" />   

             <div class="form-group center">
                 <button type="submit" name="send" id="send" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Offer</button>
              </div> 

          </form>
```

offer_save.php

```
session_start();

include_once('db_connect.php');
include_once('classes.php');

$offer_user = $_POST['user_id'];
$offer_title = $_POST['title'];
$offer_start = $_POST['start_year'] ."-" . $_POST['start_month']. "-" . $_POST['start_day'];
$offer_end = $_POST['end_year'] ."-" . $_POST['end_month']. "-" . $_POST['end_day'];


$offer_description = $_POST['description'];
$offer_category = $_POST['category'];

$offer_link = $_POST['link'];
$offer_price = $_POST['price'];


$offer_created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


if(isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) && !empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])){  
  $firmen_logo_path = firmenLogoUpload();
                     }

else    {    
//default logo
$firmen_logo_path ="../uploads/firmen_logo/porsche_logo.png";
          }  


$query = "INSERT INTO  ics_offers (offer_user_id, offer_title, offer_start, offer_end, offer_description, offer_created, offer_category, offer_price, offer_link, offer_thumb) VALUES ('$offer_user','$offer_title','$offer_start','$offer_end','$offer_description','$offer_created','$offer_category','$offer_price','$offer_link','$firmen_logo_path')";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

          $home = "../src/my_offers.php?offer_saved=ok";;

    header('Location:' . $home);
```

classes.php

```
  function firmenLogoUpload(){

$target_dir = "../uploads/firmen_logo/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["send"])) 
{

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) 
    {
        //echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else 
    {
       // echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) 
{
   // echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
    } 
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) 
{
    //echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;

}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "JPG" && $imageFileType != "JPEG" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != 

"PNG" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) 

{

}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    //echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else


 {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)== true) 
    {

       return $target_file;

    } else 
    {


       return $target_file;

    }
}
```

Comment: to upload files you need to set the form's `enctype` attribute to `multipart/form-data` ~ `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">` Also worth noting possibly is that the sql is vulnerable to sql injection!

Comment: Works like a charn.. Damn, I spent 2 hours on this issue :/.. RamRaider Thank you !!!

Comment: :) pleasure - glad it's working

Answer (score 0):

Replace`<form onSubmit="return validateForm()" action="offer_save.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask">`

With `<form onSubmit="return validateForm()" action="offer_save.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask" enctype="multipart/form-data" >`

And sanitize the user input by escaping strings using

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($vairable)
```